# Clojure defprotocol as a solution to the expression problem

Tags: clojure, polymorphism

In the book "The Joy of Clojure", `defprotocol` is offered as a solution to the *expression problem* -- "the desire to implement an existing set of abstract methods for an existing concrete class without having to change the code that defines either."

The example given is as follows:

```
(defprotocol Concatenatable
  (cat [this other]))

(extend-type String
  Concatenatable
  (cat [this other]
    (.concat this other)))

(cat "House" " of Leaves")
;=> "House of Leaves"

(extend-type java.util.List
  Concatenatable
  (cat [this other]
    (concat this other)))

(cat [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

It is suggested that this is not possible in a language like Java, but how is it different than the following?

```
public class Util {
  public static String cat(final String first,
                           final String second) {
    return first.concat(second);
  }

  public static <T> List<T> cat(final List<T> first,
                                final List<T> second) {
    final List<T> list = new List<T>(first);
    list.addAll(second);
    return list;
  }
}
```

After all, both are used similarly:

```
(cat "House" " of Leaves")
Util.cat("House", " of Leaves");
```

The Clojure function `cat` is **not** a *method* on the `String` and `List` classes, but rather an independent *function* that is overloaded to accept either `String` or `List` arguments.

Although I really like Clojure, I don't understand the claims of superiority for this construct.

Comment: They both operate in a similar way.  The difference (as highlighted by amalloy) is that in the Java case the set of participants is defined by the writer of `Util`, whereas in the Clojure case the set of participants is defined by the users of `Concatenatable`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay. You release this `cat` Java library to much fanfare, and everyone downloads it. It's so great I want to make my own `TVCommercial` type be concatenable so that I can send it to bits of your library that operate on concatenable objects.

But I can't, because you call `Util.cat(obj1, obj2)`, which has no overload for `TVCommercial`. I can't extend your code to handle my types, because I don't own your code.

You can define Concatenable as an interface to address this problem:

```
interface Concatenable {
  Concatenable cat(Concatenable other);
}
```

But now I can't write a class which is both Concatenable and... I don't know, an AnimalHandler, that handles `cat`s. Clojure's protocols solve both problems by decentralizing the dispatch functions and implementations: they live all over the place, rather than in some single location. In Java, you choose between:

- Putting all your type dispatch into a single switch/case or overloaded method
- Defining an interface mandating a method with a particular name

Clojure basically does the latter of these, but because it uses *namespaced* names, there's no danger of conflict with other protocols that think `cat` is a good function name.

Comment: The name collision problem you mention isn't really germane to the Expression Problem. Defining the interface `Concatenble` is part of the problem, though, because it locks in there being only one operation that's relevant: `cat`. Adding new operations requires opening `Concatenable` again, or possibly defining additional interfaces that participating types would have to implement.

Comment: @seh I don't think I follow. If we want to increase the number of operations that Concatenable targets must support, then we have to redefine the protocol, just like we would redefine the interface. I think Clojure allows this and just throws an unchecked exception if you call an unimplemented protocol function, but that's just papering over the problem, not solving it.

Comment: Yes, Clojure throws `IllegalArgumentException` when calling a protocol function against an instance of a type for which there's no extension of that function. The contract with protocols, though, perhaps in spirit more than letter, is that the *whole* protocol will be defined for types to which it's extended. Otherwise, what's the point of bundling the functions together in a protocol? Contrast this with CL's generic functions, which cluster together only weakly by way of same-package membership, but there's no way to express that a set of functions should all be defined together.

Answer (score 2):

Each time a new type comes along to which you'd like to apply your `cat` function, you need to "reopen" your `Util` class and add method overloads for the new target types.

The Expression Problem seeks to avoid this need, such that existing types aren't disturbed by new operations being defined and existing implemented operations aren't disturbed by new types that want to participate in those operations. The Clojure protocol example shown here doesn't fulfill the first goal, as adding a new function to a published protocol requires that all types to which the protocol is already extended define an implementation for that new method.

Comment: *adding a new function to a published protocol requires that all types to which the protocol is already extended define an implementation for that new method.* -- I wonder -- did you try?  If you execute the code in the OP and then the following, you'll observe that is not true:

(defprotocol Concatenatable
  (cat [this other])
(rev [this]))

user=> (cat "House" " of Leaves")
"House of Leaves"

No re-definition required.

Comment: No, I didn't try, but what happens when you call your new `rev` function against a string? Isn't it the case that at that point `String` only *partially* implements the protocol `Concatenatable`? Perhaps I should have written that augmenting a protocol cannot include a default implementation like one can provide with abstract classes, so previously-defined extensions to types remained *defined* but are now incomplete, and calling the new function with such a type will yield an `IllegalArgumentException`.